# WooCommerce REST API - Get all products with its variations details in a single api request

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am new to woo REST API,
 i have a php page where i need to populate all products and variations. so i am using `curl` `https://my_ip/index.php/wp-json/wc/v2/products` then im looping it and passing product id to get variations so inside loop im using `https://my_ip/index.php/wp-json/wc/v2/products/$variable_product_id/variations/` but it takes more time load because each product have more variations so is there any way get all products and variations in a single request?

like: is there any customisation can be  made in `class-wc-rest-products-controller.php` or in any query or any where in woocommerce? so that i can get the result.

mycode:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://my_ip/index.php/wp-json/wc/v2/products",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> false,

    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Basic *****************",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec( $curl) ;
curl_close( $curl );

$Product = json_decode( $response );

//after getting all product. looping all to get variations price.

foreach ( $Product as $row ){
    $product_id= $row->id;

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://my_ip/index.php/wp-json/wc/v2/products/".$product_id."/variations/",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> false,

        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Authorization: Basic **************",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache"
        ),
    ));

    $response1 = curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );


}

$variations=json_decode( $response1 );
print_r( $variations->price );

// here getting variation of particular product
```

so when we call `https://my-ip/index.php/wp-json/wc/v2/products/423` we get all product and only `variations id` belongs to it as

```
 "variations": [
        603,
        604,
        605,
        606
    ],
```

but what i need is details(price) of each variations

```
 {
        "id": 603,
        "date_created": "2018-06-18T12:45:58",
        "date_created_gmt": "2018-06-18T12:45:58",
        "date_modified": "2018-06-29T06:41:21",
        "date_modified_gmt": "2018-06-29T06:41:21",
        "description": "",
        "sku": "",
        "price": "550",
        "regular_price": "550",
}
```

note: i am creating a separate test.php page in /var/www/html/ . this page is not inside any wp-content

Answer (score 3):

I did this using their [phpLib](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce)

```
while (count($woocommerce->get('products',array('per_page' => 100, 'page' => $page))) > 0) {
        $all_products = array_merge($all_products,$woocommerce->get('products',array('per_page' => 100, 'page' => $page)));
        $page++;
      }
  
 if ($source_product->type = "variable") {
      $variation = $woocommerce->get('products/'.$source_product->id.'/variations');
      foreach ($variation as $source_child) {
          //do stuff
          
    }
}
```

Comment: hi sir is that possible to do in a separate php page and if so how to do that ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible just install their library ( with composer if you have ), and on your php class add the use statement of the library. `use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;` After that you will be abble to use the helper Class Woocomemrce client . Here is the link to the documentation on how to list all product. https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html#view-a-product

Answer (score 0):

every time in a loop you rewrite the value - `response1`

if you want save all value you need add this value in array
for example:

```
<?php

$array = array();

foreach ($Product as $row){
    $product_id= $row->id;

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://my_ip/index.php/wp-json/wc/v2/products/" . $product_id . "/variations/",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> false,

        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Authorization: Basic **************",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache"
        ),
    ));

    $array[] = json_decode( curl_exec( $curl ) );
    curl_close( $curl );
}

print_r( $array );
```

Comment: yeah thats ok just for example i showed  but the question is i need product and its variations in an api call